# WPF Refresh StaticResource

Tags: wpf, data-binding, resources

I have a ComboBox that has it's ItemsSource bound as

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource documentTemplates}}"
```

Where documentTemplates is

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="documentTemplates"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type Core:DataHelper}"
                    MethodName="GetDocumentTemplates"/>
```

The problem I have is that the document templates defined in the database could be changed by other areas of the application (or indeed by another user) and so I want to have the ItemsSource requery each time. At the moment, once the resource has been populated it will never requery. I assume that this is because it is a StaticResource, but if I swap this for a DynamicResource  I get

> A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'DynamicResrouceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty or a DependencyObject

How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep your XAML as is and whenever a requery is needed call [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.datasourceprovider.refresh.aspx) on the ObjectDataProvider.

```
(FindResource("documentTemplates") as ObjectDataProvider).Refresh();
```